# Stripe AxiosError: Request failed with status code 500

Tags: reactjs, next.js, axios, stripe-payments

I am trying for implement Stripe checkout in NextJS following this [example.](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/quickstart)

But I always get this error:

[image]

checkout.js:

```
    import React from "react";
    import Header from "../components/Header";
    import Image from "next/image";
    import { selectItems, selectTotal } from "../slices/basketSlice";

    import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
    import CheckoutProduct from "../components/CheckoutProduct";
    import Currency from "react-currency-formatter";
    import { useSession } from "next-auth/react";
    import {loadStripe} from '@stripe/stripe-js';
    
    import axios from 'axios';
    const stripePromise = loadStripe(process.env.stripe_public_key)
    
    function Checkout() {
      const items = useSelector(selectItems);
      const total = useSelector(selectTotal);
      const { data: session } = useSession();
    
      const CreateCheckoutSession = async () => {
        const stripe = await stripePromise
    
        // create checkout session
        const checkoutSession = await axios.post("/api/create-checkout-session", {
          items : items,
          email: session.user.email,
        })
        //redirect user to Stripe checkout
        const result = await stripe.redirectToCheckout({
            sessionId: checkoutSession.data.id
        })
    
        if (result.error) {
          alert(result.error.message)
        }
      }
```

create-checkout-session.js (tried to do it the way on doc page but get same relult):

```
const stripe = require('stripe')(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY)


export default async (req, res) => {
    const {
        items,
        email
    } = req.body

    // console.log(items)
    //console.log(email)
    // console.log(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY)

    const transformedItems = items.map(item => ({
        description: item.description,
        quantity: 1,
        price_data: {
            currency: 'usd',
            unit_amount: item.price * 100,
            product_data: {
                name: item.title,
                images: [item.image]
            },
        },
    }))


    const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
        payment_method_types: ['card'],
        mode: 'payment',
        shipping_rates: ['shr_1MFhHmL1z8EG1fYglFH9EBP7'],
        shipping_address_collection: {
            allowed_countries: ['GB', 'US', 'CA']
        },
        line_items: transformedItems,
        success_url: `${pocess.env.HOST}/success`,
        cancel_url: `${process.env.HOST}/checkout`,
        metadata: {
            email,
            images: JSON.stringify(items.map(item => item.image))
        }
    })
}


res.status(err.statusCode || 500).json(err.message);


res.status(200).json({
    id: session.id
})
```

I seem to me following ths Stipe formating but just keep on getting this unhelpfull error. Does anybody have a clue what it means?

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to be coming from your own server and not Stripe's API. In your `create-checkout-session.js` file, the scope of the async function seem to end prior to you running `res.status(xxx).json(...)`.

In this case, `session` variable is out of the scope of your `res.status(...).json(...)` function. Additionally, I suspect this code is sending the 500 `res.status(err.statusCode || 500).json(err.message);` as it doesn't know what `err` variable is.

Can you try fixing the scope as well as defining the `err` variable and see if that makes a difference?

Comment: if I look at create-checkout-session.js, all the elements are inside of brackets of async function. so it looks like scope is not an issue here...

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps someone.

It turns out the Stripe api version I was using had different formatting requirements, so that **description** needs to be inside **product_data array**.

I find Stripe documentation just so hard to navigate. I don't get why not just use a flat array for all items and why keep nesting - renesting the items? :(

Answer (score 0):

[The stripe-session-checkout.js images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSc2q.png)

**Remove the shipping-rates and the payment-method-types**

*It worked for me*